# ELK - How to collect logs when the system outputs one file per log?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

Let's say that I have a system that, instead of appending log lines on a given log file, outputs individual files for each 'log event'. The files have a common name pattern but contain a timestamp and another variable parameter.

```
./log/202104231115012_SYSTEM_FOO.out
./log/202104231116452_SYSTEM_BAR.out
./log/202104231117568_SYSTEM_BAZ.out
./log/202104231120711_SYSTEM_FOO.out
```

Is there any standard feature or configuration within Filebeat or Logstash to collect these logs or first do I need another background process (i.e. bash script) that continuously appends all these files in one global .log file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) input in [read](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_read_mode) mode. Note that the default operation is to delete the file after reading it, but you can change that to just log that it was read.

filebeat can also read based on a wildcard pattern. It is lighter weight than logstash, so if you are not doing other processing in the pipeline you might prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- Logstash

  - File input: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html
  - File output: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html
- Filebeat

  - Log input: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-log.html
  - File output: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/file-output.html

Using Logstash will give you the most flexible solution also in the output format, however it is as Badger states a bit more heavy on resources.